# Adding CSS in AJAX function

Tags: jquery, css

I have an AJAX function to hide and show fields of a form in HTML. I want to add some CSS in the AJAX function.

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $('#advo_other').hide();
        $('#advocate').change(function() {

            var val = $(this).val();

            $('#advo_other').hide();

            switch (val) {
                case 'Other':
                    $('#advocate') // want to add css there......
                    $('#advo_other').show();
                    break; 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the style is below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fade {
        color: #CCC;
        border-color:#CCC;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The first step should be to have a look at the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/css/.

Comment: **OMG o_O I don't know why.. but it has nothing to do with ajax.. O_o**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the addClass functionnality.

So you will have:

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $('#advo_other').hide();
        $('#advocate').change(function() {

            var val = $(this).val();

            $('#advo_other').hide();

            switch (val) {
                case 'Other':
                    $('#advocate').addClass("fade");
                    $('#advo_other').show();
                    break; 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add [CSS with Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to any element like this:

```
$('#advocate').css('color', '#005DAA');
```

Alternatively you can add a class with styling rules to the element

```
$('#advocate').addClass('fade');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
$(function() {
  $('#advo_other').hide();
  $('#advocate').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#advo_other').hide();
    switch (val){
      case 'Other':
      $('#advocate').addClass("fade");
      $('#advo_other').show();
      break;
    }
  });
});
```

`$('#advocate')` is used to select an element with id `advocate`. You may create classed in your CSS to style elements. Use `addClass("class_name")` to add some class styling to your element and `.removeClass("class_name")` to remove class styling.